# ror4 First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, edit

When I click the edit I get:
 First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty in bets/app/views/users/_form.html.erb

users/_form

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>
      prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name, "Username" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </p>
<% if @user.new_record? %>
<%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
<% else %>
<%= f.submit "Update Profile" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

in users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "You have signed up successfully."
    redirect_to posts_path
    else
    render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
  end

 def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Profile has been updated"
      redirect_to @user 
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Profile has not been updated"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  def edit
  end

  def destroy
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @user.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "Post has been destroyed."
        redirect_to posts_path
    end

  private
def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name,:password,:password_confirmation, :email)
end

end
```

in model user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password

end
```

in view/edit

```
<h2>Edit Profile</h2>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

in view/show

```
<h1>Profile Page for <%= @user.name %></h1>
<p>Email: <%= @user.email %></p>
<p><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(@user) %></p>
<%= link_to "Delete Profile",user_path(@user),method: :delete,
data: { confirm:"Are you sure you want to delete this post?"} %>
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?
p.s.: is rails 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `@user` instance variable in `edit` action:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

The reason you have this error is you pass `@user` instance variable as argument to `form_for` . This variable evaluates to `nil`, since you don't set it in your `edit` action.

BTW, you have similar bug in `update` action - I'm quite sure it will crash (with "undefined method `update` for `nil`") if you call it. You should insert line

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

on the top of `update` action.

Comment: i put it and worked but now when i press the update is says : undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass  def update
if @user.update(user_params)
flash[:notice] = "Profile has been updated"
redirect_to @user
else

Comment: @marios I predicted it. :) Check out my answer after edition.